# Как присвоить новое value для ключа обьекта js

Tags: javascript, json

Нужно получать обьект с файла JSON.В этом обьекте есть ключи значения которых функция.Когда я импортирую JSON в JS значения этих ключей определяются как строки(как я понял это нормально). Подскажите пожалуйста, как эти значения присвоить тем же ключам , только с типом функция.

```
let map = {
    "mToSm": function (a) { return a * 100 },
    "smToM": function (a) { return a / 100 },
    "mToIn": function (a) { return a * 39.37008 },
    "inToM": function (a) { return a / 39.37008 },
    "mToFt": function (a) { return a * 3.2808 },
    "ftToM": function (a) { return a / 3.2808 },
    "smToIn": function (a) { return a * 0.3937 },
    "inToSm": function (a) { return a / 0.3937 },
    "smToFt": function (a) { return a * 0.0328 },
    "ftToSm": function (a) { return a / 0.0328 },
    "inToFt": function (a) { return a * 0.0833 },
    "ftToIn": function (a) { return a / 0.0833 },
}
import data from '../data.json' assert {type: "json"};

let values = Object.values(data)
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    values[i] = new Function('return ' + values[i])
    for (let keys in data) {
        keys = values[i]
    }
}
let finalMap = {
    ...map,
    ...data,
};
```

JSON

```
{
    "mmToSm": "function (a) { return a / 10 }",
    "smToMm": "function (a) { return a * 10 }"
}
```

Вот что выдает мне консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так..

```js
let map = {
    "mToSm": function (a) { return a * 100 },
    "smToM": function (a) { return a / 100 },
    "mToIn": function (a) { return a * 39.37008 },
    "inToM": function (a) { return a / 39.37008 },
    "mToFt": function (a) { return a * 3.2808 },
    "ftToM": function (a) { return a / 3.2808 },
    "smToIn": function (a) { return a * 0.3937 },
    "inToSm": function (a) { return a / 0.3937 },
    "smToFt": function (a) { return a * 0.0328 },
    "ftToSm": function (a) { return a / 0.0328 },
    "inToFt": function (a) { return a * 0.0833 },
    "ftToIn": function (a) { return a / 0.0833 },
}
String.prototype.parseFunction = function () {
    var funcReg = /function *\(([^()]*)\)[ \n\t]*{(.*)}/gmi;
    var match = funcReg.exec(this.replace(/\n/g, ' '));
    if(match) {
        return new Function(match[1].split(','), match[2]);
    }
    return null;
};
//import data from '../data.json' assert {type: "json"};
let data = {
    "a": "function (a) { return a / 10 }",
    "b": "function (a) { return a * 10 }"
}
for (let keys in data) {
    data[keys] = data[keys].parseFunction()
}
let finalMap = {
    ...map,
    ...data,
};
console.log(finalMap.a(5),finalMap.b(5))
```

Comment: Спасибо,добрый человек)разобрался:)

Comment: На здоровье! :)